# Regex for characters in specific location in string

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using notepad++, how can I replace the `-`s noted by the carats? The dashes I want to replace occurs every 7th character in the string.

```
11.871-2-2.737-2.00334-2
      ^       ^       ^
123456781234567812345678
```

Comment: When posting questions like this on StackOverflow, it is a good idea to include multiple samples **AND** their desired outcome. i.e.: *I wan't to increase every number by 1! Example: 1->2, 2->3, 3->4* - Your Example will most likely end up with a solution that only works in a very narrow scope, because there are not enough *Samples* to actually see what's the requirement.

Comment: It is not quite clear: 7th occurrence on a line or in a file? Try [`.{6}\K-` => `^`](https://regex101.com/r/kCXMd4/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple since it's only dashes:

```
(\S*?)-
```

Begin capture group.............................. `(`

Find any number of non-space chars... `\S*`

Lazily until...............................................`?`

End capture group...................................`)`

No capture find hyphen...........................`-`

[image: Notepad++ Regex Replace]

#### Demo 1

```js
var str = `11.871-2-2.737-2.00334-2`;
var sub = `$1`;
var rgx = /(\S*?)-/g;

var res = str.replace(rgx, sub);

console.log(res);
```

> *"There is a dash (right above 1) that I would like to preserve. This seems to get rid of all the dashes in the string"*

The question clearly shows that there isn't a dash at the "1 position", but since there's a possibility that it's possible considering the pattern (n7). Don't have time to break it down, but I can refer you to a proper definition of the meta char **[`\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)**.

#### Demo 2

```js
var str = `-11.871-2-2.737-2.00334-2`;
var sub = `$1$2`;
var rgx = /\b[-]{1}(\S*?)-(\S*?)\b/g;

var res = str.replace(rgx, sub);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: There is a dash (right above 1) that I would like to preserve. This seems to get rid of all the dashes in the string

Comment: @onakaitai see demo 2, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

**Search for** `([0-9\.-]{6,6})-`
**Replace with:** `$1MY_SEPARATOR`